# Почему не создаётся внешний ключ при миграции в laravel?

Tags: laravel

Версия базы данных:

**mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.3.13-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2**

Миграции:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('login')->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('second_name')->nullable();
        $table->string('patronymic')->nullable();
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('company_id')
              ->references('id')->on('company');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
    });
}
```

---

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('company', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Ошибка:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `dealer`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint i
>   s incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_company_id_foreign` foreign key (`company_id`) references `company` (`id`))

---

> UPD Добавление в метод `run` первой миграции кода ниже — тоже не помогло.

```
    Schema::table('users', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('company');
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При установке индекса `foreign` очень важно соблюдать тот же тип поля, на который ссылается индекс. У вас это соблюдается.
Второе, скорее всего первая миграция - это создание таблицы `users`, а уже вторая - `companies` (рекомендуется называть таблицы во множественном числе, а модель - в единственном). Т.е. при запуске миграций создается таблица `users`, в которой есть индекс `foreign`, но он не может быть добавлен, т.к. `companies` таблицы еще не существует